# Web Apps - How to Dynamically Present Announcements

Tags: database, web-applications

I am developing a web app that has a page that displays updates and announcements. I am not familiar with how other websites accomplish this. Do people store their announcements/updates in a database and just update their database whenever they have a new announcement?

What are the standard methods that people use to accomplish something like this at scale?

Comment: Should users see the announcment every time they visit the site, or one time only (like a notification).

Comment: @moeassal I was planning on having an "Updates" page on my website that displays information about patches and future plans for the website as well as provide an area for people to provide feedback on recent changes. Users wouldn't receive notifications, but could visit that page to see recent changes. I thought that hard-coding in updates into the HTML of the page may not be sustainable, so I thought that they should be loaded in from somewhere. I was curious how larger websites did this at scale (as many sites have "Announcements" pages and things of that nature).

Comment: I think you don't know the concept of 'rendering'. How do you manage your server? What programming language do you use? Or maybe your question is theoratical, is it?

Comment: @moeassal It's more theoretical (you can assume a NodeJS + Express server, if you want). My question is that if you have an announcements page that requires frequent manual changes, should the information that populates this announcements page be stored in some kind of database that an admin can push updates to or hard coded into the html of the page (or something else)? Hard coding it seems like bad practice, but having to push updates to a database whenever you want add a new announcement seems like a pain.

Comment: Well, I made an online community site once. And using a database that doesn't require a dedicated server but a file (sqlite) isn't that hard actually. Why should the editing be 'manual'? Usually they dedicate a webpage for publishing such announcments. You can think of it as 'moderators' interface in an online community.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a database, and having moderators that manage the updates and announcements, as suggested by @moe. The updates could for example be in a table with UpdateID, UpdateTitle, UpdateMessage, UpdateStartDate, and UpdateEndDate. The updates would show between the two dates and then automagically disappear after the end date. And if Announcements needed to be seen at least once before disappearing, create a table more like AnnouncementID, AnnouncementTitle, AnnouncementMessage, and then link to table of users with a yes/no flag in the connector table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want is a backend that runs a websocket port for clients to bind to. So a client would send his request to post an announcement, this could be via the web socket or any other API( REST, SOAP, GraphQL).

The server can then save the announcements in its Database or/and push update to all the clients attached that an announcement was added through the websocket port. Then the client can handle the response from the server according to its logic.

To fetch announcements for clients which were not connected at the time of announcement via websocket, you can just reply with all the announcements made after a client disconnected.

Comment: This is the best answer. Websockets is usually correct whenever you want to "push" data to the client. With client pull-based solutions, you need to keep track of each client's latest received notification and set thresholds for selecting which notifications to provide them when they hit the pull endpoint. You also would generally want to weave them into page loads.

Another source you could look at would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible solution, all with different degree of difficulty and flexibility:

**1. Hardcode everything in your HTML page**

It's the easier solution in the short term, but it would become harder and harder as the projects grows. I would not suggest doing this even for smaller projects.

**2. Save the list on a committed data source**

For example, create a JSON file in your project with the following structure:

```
[
  { 
    "type": "announcement",
    "date": "2020-08-18",
    "title": "New announcement!",
    "content": "Bla bla bla...",
  },
  { 
    "type": "update",
    "date": "2020-08-18",
    "title": "Version 2.1.0",
    "content": "Here is the changelog: ...",
  },
]
```

Then your webapp can load this file and render it accordingly. This approach has some advantages:

- You don't need to rewrite all the boilerplate html everytime
- The changes on the update page are committed, so they are easier to review or cancel

However, you still need to insert html in your `content` field and that could be problematic to do by hand everytime (especially if you need to add images, tables or more complex elements). Also, the changes are in the codebase, so they can not be delegated to a not-technical person (such as the marketing manager).

Also, it is not very efficient to load and parse a json file everytime. You can add some caching, but it's still not as performant as a database

**3. Save the list manually in the database**

This solution is very similar to number (2). It provides some performance improvement, but most of the other disadvantages remains valid.

**4. Use a database and implement a GUI for creating/editing/publishing announcements**

The ideal solution is to use a database, while also implementing in the backend a restricted area where it is possible to manage the announcements using a WYSIWYG editor.

Advantages:

- Maximum flexibility and it does not require writing the HTML by hand everytime
- Anyone can write and publish the announcement, it does not have to be a developer

Disadvantages:

- You need to develop the whole editing/publishing system

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats your programming language or technologies you're using. But, I guess you want a realtime updates and announcement. I'm suggesting you to use realtime databases like FCM to handle it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=id

In this example, it using NodeJS:

https://thecodebarbarian.com/sending-web-push-notifications-from-node-js.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you want to handle it.
Some use this technique of storing in a database and updating it.

Another approach is that you can simply use a web crawler to import the announcement/notices if you are taking references from another websites and you won't need to create a database too. But, your website will be little bit slow but will save the memory for database.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method for putting text onto webpages without hardcoding it is using a content management system or CMS. This can be big and complex, or simple and lightweight.

The approach I've seen work best is to use a "headless CMS", which gives non-technical people a UI to enter the content, and an API which allows your application to grab that content (e.g. as JSON), and render it in whichever framework you're using. This works for "Announcements", or other text content like FAQs, terms & conditions etc.

Another approach is to use a "static site generator" which takes text in a specific format and spits it out as HTML. You could use this to build a pipeline to take "announcements" written in markdown and committed to Git, which are converted by the static site generator into an HTML snippet, which you then render using your NodeJS application.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, a CMS (content management system) is probably the way to go. If you haven't decided on how to build your web app, I would strongly advise you to use a web framework.

If you are in search of a good solution I would recommend Django and Django CMS.
Both are well documented, open-source and can scale as needed.

Django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/contents/

Django CMS:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/